# I'm not seeing one of my grid rows....(two WrapPanel ListBox's in a XAML Grid)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding, datasource

I have two ListBox's in a grid. The ListBox ItemsPanelTemplate is set to "WrapPanel." I'm expecting to see two separate rows but only see 1. I'm very new to xaml. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<navigation:Page
x:Class="BusMasterControl.Home" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
xmlns:riaControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DomainServices" 
xmlns:ds="clr-namespace:BusMasterControl.Web"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:BusMasterControl.Controls" 
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:BusMasterControl.Controls.Converters"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignWidth="640" 
d:DesignHeight="480" 
Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:UriToMachineNameConverter x:Key="uriToMachineNameConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="busMasterControlDomainDataSource2" LoadSize="500" QueryName="GetResourceByDomainAndUriFilter" AutoLoad="True">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <ds:BusMasterControlDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="domain" Value="//bus.mydomain.com" />
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="uriFilter" Value="red" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>

        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
            <riaControls:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="resourceId" Direction="Ascending" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="busMasterControlDomainDataSource" LoadSize="500" QueryName="GetResourceByDomainAndUriFilter" AutoLoad="True">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <ds:BusMasterControlDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="domain" Value="//bus.test.mydomain.com" />
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="uriFilter" Value="red" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
            <riaControls:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="resourceId" Direction="Ascending" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

    <ListBox Name="machines2" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=busMasterControlDomainDataSource2}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Controls:BusBench 
                   Background="Gray"
                   BorderBrush="Black"
                   BorderThickness="1"
                   Caption="{Binding Path=uri, Converter={StaticResource uriToMachineNameConverter},FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Name="machines" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=busMasterControlDomainDataSource}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Controls:BusBench 
               Background="Gray"
               BorderBrush="Black"
               BorderThickness="1"
               Caption="{Binding Path=uri, Converter={StaticResource uriToMachineNameConverter},FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Also, I must be doing something wrong with the data source. I can't imagine you have to create that whole "riaControls:DomainDataSource" tag just to execute the same query method with different parameters. Are the two issues related?

Comment: You should add to your tags if this is Silverlight, WPF, Windows 8 or ... and remove the entity-framework tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you didn't specify that the first list box belongs to grid row `0` and the second to grid row `1`. `0` is default for the `Grid.Row` attached property so you don't need to specify it for the first list box. But for the second you need to set it explicitly to `1`:

```
<ListBox Name="machines" Grid.Row="1" ... >
  ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma! That was it. Also, the second part of my question... Do I have to create a separate riaControls:DomainDataSource block  for every GetResourceByDomainAndUriFilter query with different parameters? Or is there a more compact way... Like in the ItemSource binding? What would the syntax be?

Comment: @smadirondack: I have no idea. I suggest that you open a separate new question for this because it is quite different to your original question.